# Unable to log Trace events to Application Insights

Tags: c#, azure, logging, trace, azure-application-insights

We have recently on-boarded our Azure app service to AppInsights.

I am using below code for using traces:

```
 Trace.WriteLine("Api v1 called by user");
 Trace.TraceWarning("Tracking warning via AI");
```

The Trace class is referenced from `System.Diagnostics` .

I have **manually** added the below piece of code in my web.config as per [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/application-insights/app-insights-asp-net-trace-logs#troubleshooting) page.:

```
<system.diagnostics>
      <trace autoflush="false" indentsize="4">
        <listeners>
          <add name="myListener"
               type="System.Diagnostics.TextWriterTraceListener"
               initializeData="TextWriterOutput.log" />
          <remove name="Default" />
        </listeners>
      </trace>
    </system.diagnostics>
  </configuration>
```

However, `Trace.WriteLine and TraceWarning` events are **NOT** collected.

What works for me is directly using the AppInsights Telemetry library to use the TrackTrace events as shown below.

```
telemetry.TrackTrace("Tracking trace via AI for user:", SeverityLevel.Information); //This works
```

I would like to **make use of the Trace WriteLine and TraceWarning** and want these to be seen in the AppInsights as the latter requires us to change all the references of the TelemetryClient library.

I have added the latest `ApplicationInsights.TraceListener NuGet` package. However, that didn't change my web.config file. I have to manually add the `<system.diagnostics>` tag as seen above.
 Is there anything I am missing?

Answer (score 1):

Adding ApplicationInsights.TraceListener NuGet package should automatically modify Web.Config as shown in this link:
https://github.com/Microsoft/ApplicationInsights-dotnet-logging#systemdiagnostics

if Web.config is not modified for some reason, please manually add this following

```
<system.diagnostics>
    <trace>
      <listeners>
        <add name="myAppInsightsListener" type="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.TraceListener.ApplicationInsightsTraceListener, Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.TraceListener" />
      </listeners>
    </trace>
  </system.diagnostics>
```

Comment: Btw - if you application in .net core based, then you need to use 2.6.0-beta3 of the tracelistener package. https://github.com/Microsoft/ApplicationInsights-dotnet-logging/blob/develop/CHANGELOG.md#version-260-beta3

Comment: Thanks @cjthomas. I had to add that block of code manually as adding the NuGet package didn't change web.config. However, I still don't see the System.Diagnostic.Trace. 1 strange thing is that I don't see an option to 'enable log adapter option' after clicking on the 'Configure AppInsights' option in Visual studio. Am I missing anything?

Comment: What tool are you using for adding nuget? I used Visual Studio 2017, and adding this nuegt to the WebApplication modified the web.config. Also traces are collected by application insights as well. Can you try this again, and make sure the modified web.config as well as applicationinsights.config (containing instrumentation key) and copied to the server where this is deployed.

Comment: Please try to follow instructions here and see if this is helping: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/application-insights/app-insights-asp-net-trace-logs#manual-installation